# Go - time - milliseconds

Tags: go

I need the time in milliseconds for what could be a large volume of transactions, so I want something that is correct, and fast. Will the following work and do the job best? :

```
    iMilli  := int((time.Nanoseconds() % 1e6) / 1e3)
```

TIA

Comment: "Time in milliseconds" normally means "time since a particular epoch in milliseconds" - that code will only give you the *fraction of a second* in millis (i.e. 0-999). Is that really what you're after?

Comment: Simply using time.Nanoseconds() / 1e6 should be enough. It won't fit in a 32 bit int though.

Comment: I am after the number of milliseconds in the current second which will convert to 3 digits in a string. time.LocalTime() gives me the rest of the date and time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Since this answer was first written, escape analysis code has been added to the Go compilers.  This allows the compiler to avoid unnecessary allocations in certain situations, including (probably) the one described below.  With the latest weeklies, therefore, it may be just as good to use a more straightforward call to time.Nanoseconds(). Please do your own profiling.*

Most of the time functions cause a heap allocation (that then subsequently needs to be collected, causing a pause in your application).  So if you're looking up the time frequently, which it sounds like you are, you'll need to use syscall.Gettimeofday() directly (it's the function that the other time functions end up calling anyway).  See the discussion here for more information:

http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/f2209022f43efcca?pli=1

The solution I'm using is to pre-allocate a `tv syscall.Timeval`, and each time through my inner loop I do this:

```
syscall.Gettimeofday(&tv)
```

You can then get the milliseconds with:

```
(int64(tv.Sec)*1e3 + int64(tv.Usec)/1e3)
```

I've found this to perform a lot better than calling time.Nanoseconds() or one of the other higher-level time functions.

Comment: FWIW, I get the current time about every 30 microseconds, and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 3):

There's 1e9 nanoseconds in a second, and 1e6 nanoseconds in a millisecond, so you'd do something like this:

```
func getTimeString() string {
    now := time.Nanoseconds()
    localTime := time.SecondsToLocalTime(now/1e9)
    miliSeconds := (now % 1e9) / 1e6
    return fmt.Sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d",localTime.Year,localTime.Month,localTime.Day,localTime.Hour,localTime.Minute,localTime.Second,miliSeconds)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. For the timestamp of YYYYMMDDhhmmss I was using :<pre><code>
sTimestamp := time.LocalTime().Format("20060102150405"); 
</code></pre>

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add more. Thanks for that info. That appears to solve the current millisecond problem for me. For the timestamp of YYYYMMDDhhmmss I was using :

sTimestamp := time.LocalTime().Format("20060102150405"); 

Is it not possible to use that (time.LocalTime().Format) and also obtain the nano or millisecond value that is relevant? Ie. Without having to extract .Year, .Month, etc.

Comment: Well obviously you can't do one call to time.Nanoseconds() and piece that together with one call to time.LocalTime(), but with the above code you should be able to do e.g. `localTime.Format("20060102150405") + fmt.Sprintf(".%03d",miliSeconds);`

Comment: From what I have tried and what you have said, your original answer appears to be the only way to do it. So I will use that. The time.LocalTime().Format() is a nice clean way to get the timestamp, but as far as I can tell, it cannot be used with milliseconds because the are not at the same millisecond and the second could rollover.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use following code to get current time milliseconds after 1 Jun 1970

```
time.Now().UnixNano()%1e6/1e3
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the question asked you to do. The question asked for `time.Now().UnixNano() % 1e6 / 1e3`.